# change http to https but images don't goes

Tags: wordpress, image, http, https

i have change http to https but images don't goes , some pages show me mixed content, because the url is https, and the image is http, so how can I change the image to https???

I use Wordpress.

Comment: Really Simple SSL.

Comment: if you want to get suggestions on which plugin to use, then it's out of topic. if you want to fix the problem, your information is too few. provide more details, such as what you did, how you did, which urls loding through http, where that images called into your page and etc

Answer (score 0):

Is the content on the same web server as your website?

## Checklist

Check that the paths of the images are also https:// if you forced HTTPS Redirect on your website.
Is your webserver allowing non-https traffic?
Have you cleared your browser/DNS Cache?

Open Inspect Element by pressing **Ctrl + Shift + I** , go to the **Sources** tab and check that the images are being loaded as resources on the website.